# PHP PCRE match bigger than, lower than string values

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Considering the validation of a input value with PCRE that might contain :

```
200
<200
>200
<=200
>=200
```

What would be the best approach to match `<=` or `>=` sequence of characters? So far I have this :

```
[<|>|<=|>=]{0,2}\d+
```

Comment: Maybe `(?:<|>)?=?\d+`.

Comment: Also works, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaking a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with the [grouping operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).  Consider:

```
(?:<|>|<=|>=)?\d+
```

Or, if you want to save the groupings for later logic:

```
(<|>|<=|>=)?(\d+)
```

Comment: I managed to find the answer. Regarding yours, wouldnt (?:<|>|<=|>=)?\d+ be more like it? Otherwise it wont match a numeric string alone

Comment: Correct; I missed that detail.  I'll just edit that briefly.